# AWS classic load balancer caching content from ec2 instance?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a AWS EC2 server hosting a website with tomcat9. When I introduced Classic Load Balancer, now when I update my HTML files, it won't reflect on my page. Even after I delete the webpage from EC2 instance, the page shows up on my domain.
I have just one EC2 instance with 1 Load Balancer.

Comment: Be more specific. What have you done? What is the current result? What kind or error do you receive? What is the expected result?

Comment: ELB doesn't cache. Any chance this is cached on the client? Do you see different cache headers in the two cases (with and without ELB)?

Comment: Any chance you are using CloudFront in addition to ELB? ELB does not cache. CloudFront does.

Comment: There must be another explanation.  It's definitely not a classic balancer doing this.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your comments. I have one EC2 instance running tomcat9. I store my html files at /var/www/html/ . This server hosts this pages at https://www.example.com. This set up was all working fine and every time I update the files in html folder, it used to reflect on http://www.example.com. I added a classic load balancer to this set up. Added EC2 instance to this load balancer. Now when I update the files in html folder, changes are not reflecting on http://www.example.com